# Communication between Electron applications

Tags: electron

I have two applications written on Electron. How to pass data from one to another?

This should work on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Hi! In order to get an answer to your question you should provide more information. What have you tried so far? What went wrong? Do you have any relevant code? etc

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !